# Angular.During ng build --prod get error : Uncaught (in promise): Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-elements

Getting following error when using external **angular elements (webcomponents)** in my angular application.

**Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined**

It occurs only when building in production mode (ng build --prod), when optimisation is set true and with lazy loading.

package.json dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```

Below are the reproduction steps .

Application src (GIT repo):

https://github.com/gowthamr123/repro-app

after running npm install do ng serve and go to below url :

http://localhost:4200/selfcare/tariff-change

It will work fine.

Now run in production mode ng serve --prod

Error occurs :

**Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try running `ng serve --aot`. This way you get a better idea where it errors, instead of looking through minified code without source maps

Comment: The only weird thing I can find in your code is that you have the `zone.js` polyfill commented, and that you have a double array in the import from the recommendation.module `[RoundProgressModule]`. If you do not want to use zone.js you should add `ngZone: 'noop'` to the `bootstrapModule` call

Comment: Hi Pierre, 

ng serve --aot runs fine without any errors. Problem is only with ng build --prod

Comment: Have  you looked at my other comments about zone.js and `RoundProgressModule`?

Comment: Restart your app and run the command !

Comment: Hi Pierre, Error still occurs if I use only RoundProgressModule. Also if I use ngZone: 'noop' then there is error "Zone already loaded" and also "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined".

Comment: @Gowthamr.cs have you found any solution for this issue??